# AS3 switch/case difference with or without parenthesis

Tags: actionscript-3, switch-statement, case, parentheses

In AS3 it is possible to write code without parenthesis, like such

```
switch(letter)
{
    case "A":
        // some code
        break;
    case "B":
        // some more code
        break;
}
```

or with the parenthesis, like this

```
switch(continent)
{
    case "A":
    {
        // some code
        break;
    }
    case "B":
    {
        // some more code
        break;
    }
}
```

What is the difference, and why use one over another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. This would also be valid:

```
switch
{
    case "A":
    {
        {
            // some code
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can add a `{ }` block wherever you like.

Comment: Also note that adding brackets does **NOT** break the case. For this reason I recommend against using it, as it can create confusion as to where the case will break. I've personally seen developers on more than one occasion forget to put the `break` statement, apparently thinking the closing `}` was enough.